# Accessing inputField Values Created Inside apex:repeat

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I need help in getting values from VF component page, just for the sake of clarity I have added very few fields to make my point across.

How to access inputField values that are created inside an apex:repeat.

When I do `system.debug('updateMe >>>' + detailList)` I see there is old data but NOT the updated value.

Here is the code snippet

VF Component:

```
<apex:component>
  <apex:attribute name="record" description="my custom object" type="meter__c" required="true" />  

    <!-- more fields -->
         <apex:inputField value="{!record.meter_reading__c}"/>
         <apex:inputField value="{!record.desc__c}"/>
</apex:component>
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page Controller="MeterReading" >
  <apex:form > 
   <apex:pageBlock>    
      <apex:pageBlockSection>
         <apex:repeat value="{!detailList}" var="detail"> 
            <c:meter_vf_comp record="{!detail}" />
         </apex:repeat>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>
   <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!updateMe}"/>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class MeterReading 
{
  public List<meter__c> detailList { get; set; }

public MeterReading() 
{
   detailList = [/*SOQL*/];  //loading the data and display in repeat...
 }

public PageReference updateMe() {
    system.debug('updateMe >>>' + detailList);  
    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: hmm Just now tried same code in my dev org I am able to get updated value.. Can you just add rerender in save and give a try..

Comment: did you use standard object or was it custom object? i did not get rerender part where do you want me to add `<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!updateMe}" rerender='???' />` here?

Comment: Yes in save button... You code looks good to me.. may be issue with other part of code..

Comment: just rerender?, i'm looking at the debug and did not see any updated values

Comment: does not make any diff by adding `rerender`

Comment: Yeah does not make any diff by adding rerender.. I am just guessing.. because same code working fine in my org..

Comment: (1) commandButton w/o rerender simply refreshes page so I wouldn't expect that to matter; (2) is what you are showing the entire code base?  Perhaps you are getting some setter error when the commandButton does a POST.  Add an `apex:pageMessages` to make sure there isn't a hidden error

Answer (score -1):

One of the things about visualforce is you should explicitly call your getters if needed .Check [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_methods.htm)

While loading in constructor is ok still to make sure the list is always populated I would code this as per lazy loading pattern

```
public with sharing class MeterReading {

  list<meter__c> detailList ;

  public List<meter__c> getdetailList() { 
     if(detailList == null){
       detailList =[//SOQL];
     }
     return detailList ;
   }

  public List<meter__c> setdetailList(list<meter__c> detailList){
     this.detailList = detailList;
  }

  public MeterReading() {

  }

  public PageReference updateMe() {
  system.debug('updateMe >>>' + detailList);  
  return null;
 }

}
```